# What process are started by the system?

Tags: startup, process

How to find what process are started during bootup process. Are there any ways to find using any command, like one found in windows

```
<msconfig>.
```

For more about please read.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSConfig

Comment: You shouldn't assume that people remember those commands. Lots of us, if we ever did, stopped using Windows years ago. Describe it more thoroughly instead.

Comment: Sorry for that,  Here it goes .. MSConfig is a troubleshooting tool. The main function of MSConfig is to temporarily disable or re-enable software, device drivers or Windows services that run during startup process to help user decide the cause of problem.  It can disable or re-enable software, device drivers and Windows services that run at startup, or change boot parameters. **refer:[MsConfig - Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSConfig)**

Answer (score 1):

Most of the scripts inside `/etc/init` and `/etc/init.d` are run during bootprocess if you haven't changed any of their configurations. There is an application called BootUpManager i.e. `bum`.

`sudo apt-get install bum`

[image]

which will let you configure bootup scripts.

Ubuntu uses upstart i.e. `/etc/init/*.conf` for bootup scripts

Answer (score 0):

Most of the bootup processes get low PID numbers [or so it seems]. So try this

`$ ps -ef|less`

and view the low PID processes.

Also, as previously mentioned, check /etc/init/ and /etc/init.d/